# Вывод в поле ввода текста другой программы

Tags: python

Есть код (Speech to text) и он работает в командной строке и при преобразовании речи в текст вывод текста так же остаётся в командной строке , но мне нужно чтоб он писался в поле ввода текста в котором я нахожусь , то-есть в поисковую строку в браузере или же в мессенджер в поле набора сообщения , так же как это реализовано в windows speech to text при нажатии win+h, как реализовать это в этом коде ?

Python 3.8

```
import sounddevice as sd
import vosk, queue, json

q = queue.Queue()

devices = sd.query_devices()
print("Select device id: \n", devices)

dev_id = 0

try:
    dev_id = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Using default value: 0")

samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(dev_id, 'input')['default_samplerate'])

try:
    model = vosk.Model("model")
    with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize=8000, device=dev_id, dtype='int16', channels=1, callback=(lambda i, f, t, s: q.put(bytes(i)))):
        rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)
        while True:
            data = q.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                data = json.loads(rec.Result())["text"]
                print(data)
                
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print('\nDone')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный простой вариант решения как по мне - использовать модуль `keyboard`:

`keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, func)` - вставляете в свой код и `hotkey` заменяете на строку с вашими горячими клавишами, `func` заменяете на вашу функцию `translator` где будет ваше преобразования речи в текст.

`keyboard.write(text)` - заменяете `print`  на эту функцию и text на текст который будет выведен.

Идея такова: Нажимая хоткей запускалась ф-ция преобразования речи в текст и с помощью  `keyboard.write` имитировала нажатия на клавиатуру с вашим текстом, то есть для этого пользователь должен удерживать курсор на на нужном текст-инпуте.

Comment: Получилось , спасибо.

Comment: @anon если этот ответ - решение, можете отметить его галкой и поставить плюс.